# reactdom.render() not working in code sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

reactdom not working in code sandbox for react
Html file has:

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>


<script src="scr/index.js">
```

JavaScript (named index)file has:

```
ReactDOM.render(<p>Hello</p>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

the line of code in js is not recognized and error pops up that line:
ReactDOM.render is not a function

Comment: please post how you import react and reactDom

Answer (score 0):

You need to call render method from div with id="root", not from ReactDOM.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
 <p>Hello</p>
);
```

or

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<p>Hello</p>);
```